# google-httpclient JSON definition

Tags: java, android, json

When the JSON is:

```java
{
     "result":200,
     "data", "my data"
}
```

The definition of the class can be:

```java
class HttpResult
{
    @Key
    public int result;

    @Key
     public String data;

}
```

When the JSON root is a array and has no Key:

```java
[
    {
        "result:200",
        "data":"data1"
    },
    {
        "result":404,
        "data":"data2"
    }
]
```

Then the definition of the class is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same class definition, it's just a `Collection` of them instead of one.